# Monitor average CPU usage and RAM usage on one process linux

Tags: linux, unix, process

Is there any way to monitor one process' CPU usage and RAM usage over time on linux? I am trying to change to a cheaper VPS and need to work out what level of CPU and RAM I need!

Comment: Shouldn't you be more interested in *maximum* memory usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read `man 5 proc`, especially the `/proc/[pid]/stat` entry and the `utime`, `stime` fields. `/proc/[pid]/status` or `/proc/[pid]/statm` might be of interest for you as well.

then use `cron` or whatever means needed to collect 'snapshots' of `/proc/[pid]/stat` for your process over a period of time. then visualize what you have grabbed.

a simple 'collector' works like this (for a process with the pid '29777'):

```
% while true; do cat /proc/29777/stat; sleep 1; done
```

to make life easier, you could also use the [systat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html) package which includes several means to collect data over time:

http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html

Comment: Sounds an interesting idea, i'll give it a go and update you with the result.

Answer (score 4):

pidstat is a very good tool for the cpu part of your question.

http://xmodulo.com/2012/08/how-to-measure-average-cpu-utilization.html

Answer (score -1):

`top` command should give you all the info you need.

Comment: Top only provides instantaneous snapshots of CPU and memory usage. The OP asks how to collect aggregate statistics over time.